# MySql No database selected в VB.NET с запросом SHOW FULL COLUMNS

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mysqlconnector, metadata

Имеем такой код получения полей из таблицы в базе данных.

```
        Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("Строка подключения...")

        Try
            connection.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка открытия базы")
        End Try

        Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SHOW FULL COLUMNS IN " & "Имя таблицы" & ";", connection)

        Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader

        '   Цикл по полям в таблице
        Do While dr.Read

        Loop
        dr.Close()
        command.Dispose()
        connection.Dispose()
```

Во время выполнения `command.ExecuteReader` получаю ошибку "No database selected".

Понимаю что надо перед этим выбрать базу с которой работаю, например выполнением запроса "USE databasename;", но не понимаю как кошерно это реализовать в данном коде.
Прошу помощи.

Comment: Самое простое - указывать не только имя таблицы, но и имя схемы. А самое кошерное - получать данные не через `SHOW`, а из `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`. Ну и можно (да что можно -
 нужно!) указать параметр `Database` в строке подключения.

Comment: В строке подключения нельзя указать параметр Database так как подключение может быть к разным базам в программе, то есть к нескольким базам в разных ситуациях и коннект универсален в данном случае. А про указание схемы как то не подумал, спасибо.